# Increase date input button clickable area

Tags: javascript, html, css, date, input

I have a date input element.

```
<input type="date" >
```

[image]

The following red square is the default area the button can be clicked to open the date picker:
[image]

I wonder if it is possible to increase this area to make it easier to click, something wider like this:
[image]

Solutions in html, javascript or css are ok.

Comment: An input is clickable on its entire width by default, you don't have to specifically click the icon to open the calendar. Or maybe this is browser-dependent, which browser forces you to click the icon?

Comment: I tried Chrome, Opera and Edge, I have to click in that area to open the date picker

Comment: Ah ... It seems to work differently in FF.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using `::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator` pseudo-element

```css
#date-inp::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  padding-left: 100px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="date-inp"/>
```

Comment: @User86.3 You're a life saver. You're the king. You made my day.